# How can I judge whether a mail send sccess or not use Python?

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I know that I can use `smtplib` module in Python to send a mail like below:

```
smtp = SMTP_SSL(p_hostname)
smtp.set_debuglevel(0)
smtp.ehlo(p_hostname)
smtp.login(p_username, p_password)

msg = MIMEText(p_mailtext, "plain", p_mailencoding)
msg["Subject"] = Header(p_mailsubject, p_mailencoding)
msg["from"] = p_from
msg["to"] = p_to

smtp.sendmail(p_from, p_to, msg.as_string())

smtp.quit()
```

If I set `set_debuglevel` as 1, I can see the debug infomation such as `send OK` or `send fail`. but can I use Python to get those informations so I can judge the mail is send success or not?

Comment: check the inbox :)

Comment: Even if the SMTP submission is successful, the mail might not go through. The server usually just queues it, and it could get an error later when it tries to deliver.

Comment: As Barmar said, this mostly depends on what you consider "success".  You can get delivery notices (failed or successful) _days_ after sending.

Comment: I assume "if server not send me any failed information" is success. I wanna know can I read the feed back informations from the server use Python so I can make some judgements.